# Keycloak client mapper to show the relam name as individual attibute in JWT token

Tags: jwt, keycloak, access-token

By default keycloak (here version 11) provides information about the realm, a token was fetched for, only parsing the iss attribute of the token payload. e.g.

```
{
  "exp": ...,
  "iat": ...,
  "jti": "...",
  "iss": "http://localhost:8088/idp-provider-context/auth/realms/realmname",
  "aud": [...
```

Is there a build in way, like a client mapper, to add the information about the realm name directly as a dedicated attribute to the JWT-token?

One workaround would be to add an attribute "realmname" to each user and setting the realmname as the value. But on the one hand this seems to be a bit messy, as it is redundant information. On the other hand this could speed up the application a bit, as tokens/users without this attribute or the wrong value in it could be already count as invalid without requesting the backend. This would identify users not created in the desired process, defined for the application.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of a user attribute, use a `Client Mapper` Instead. For that go to:

- Select your `realm`
- Go to `clients`
- Select the appropriate `client` for your use-case

**(For the OLD Keycloak UI)**

- Go to `Mappers`
- Click `Create`
- In `Mapper type` select `Hardcoded claim`
- Fill up the field `Token Claim Name` as `realm name`
- Fill up the field `Claim value` as `the name of the realm`
- Fill up the renaming fields, accordingly.
- Click on `Save`

**(For the NEW Keycloak UI)**

- Go to the tab `Client Scopes`
- Click on the scope -dedicated (e.g., test-dedicated in my example)

[image]

- Click on `Configure a new mapper` (or `Add Mapper` >  `By configuration` if you have already created mappers before for this client)

[image]

- Select `Hardcoded claim`
- Fill up the field `Token Claim Name` as `realm name`
- Fill up the field `Claim value` as `the name of the realm`
- Fill up the renaming fields, accordingly.
- Click on `Save`

The client will be the client that you are using to authenticate against.