# Add alias name for keycloak realm and add this as part of token

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

During realm creation on Keycloak , I want to add an alias name for it like for starbucks : STB  , Cafe Coffee Day : CCD etc. And this alias name should be available as part of token. So other application can use it.

I am planning to use realm display name property for this but not sure how to add this as part of access token. Can configure client scope for this. If it is possible then how to access realm display name in client scope.

Please help me.

Comment: Does using hardcoded claim as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65184441/keycloak-client-mapper-to-show-the-relam-name-as-individual-attibute-in-jwt-toke works for you? Otherwise i guess you need to develop a custom protol mapper

Comment: Hi Sirish, Thanks for reply. I have tried hardcoded claim and it is working for me. But we will have many realm and this will become extra job for administrator to manually configure hard coded claim under the client. DO we have any OOB mapper , by which we can directlly map realm attribute to token.         Thanks

Comment: If you are only looking for OOB, one possibility is to create a custom default client scope at the realm level /auth/admin/master/console/#/realmname/client-scopes and add hard coded claim there. But this only works for oidc clients, and you may be need to add this for already created clients because as per my observation new client scope becomes default only for new clients created after adding the default scope.